# Magento 2: How to reindex specific indexer method in Magento 2 programatically

Tags: magento2, reindex

I can reindex **a specific indexer method** by following way in Magento 1.x

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```

How to reindex `catalog_product_price` indexer in Magento 2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterfaceFactory`.

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $indexerFactory;


    /**
     * @param IndexerInterfaceFactory $indexerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterfaceFactory $indexerFactory,
    ) {
        $this->indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;

    }

    /**
     * @param string $indexerId
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterface
     */
    public function getIndexer($indexerId)
    {
        return $this->indexerFactory->create()->load($indexerId);
    }

    public function executeIndex() {

        this->getIndexer('catalog_product_price')->reindexAll();
    }
```

Comment: I already have a custruct function:

   public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
    {
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

How to combine it with your construct function?

Comment: Need to add `\Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterfaceFactory` to the current constructor.

Comment: Will I have to call executeIndex function anywhere or it will be called automatically? Actually I have execute() method and within this function I want to reindex "catalog_product_price".

Comment: Technically, you can call `$this->indexerFactory->create()->load('catalog_product_price')->reindexAll()` in the execute method.

Comment: How can I reindex all indexer method I mean I want to reindex all instead of specific indexer method

Comment: You can try with Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor::reindexAll()

Comment: it is not working. I simply put in controller "execute" method but not working

Comment: You need to inject `Magento\Indexer\Model\Processor` in your constructor.

Comment: Can you come on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49770/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-arshad-hussain).